# Perf of select mysql query is really bad

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select

I'm not sure why this query is taking 4 minutes to complete:

```
SELECT 
    su.sid,u.uid,u.display_name,u.locale 
FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN subscription_user su ON su.uid = u.uid 
ORDER BY u.display_name DESC 
LIMIT 0,25;
```

Well, I know it's due to the order, remove it and it's very fast. If I change to using INNER JOIN instead it's fast but the issue is not all users may be in the subscription_user table.

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `password` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
  `display_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `locale` varchar(8) DEFAULT 'en',
  `last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `auth_type` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auth_data` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inactive` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `receive_email` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `stateid` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner_group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `signature` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `raw_signature` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `round_robin` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `stateid` (`stateid`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `user_type` (`user_type`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `name` (`display_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28343 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `subscription_user` (
  `sid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `forum_user` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`,`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I guess the problem is with missing key 'uid' on table 'subscription_user'

Comment: It's part of the primary key on `subscription_user`

Comment: so? Your join is ON su.uid = u.uid

Comment: Have you tried adding an index to `display_name`?

Comment: Guess I'm not sure what you mean then. `uid` field is a primary key on both `user` and `subscription_user` tables.

Comment: this key is most probably not used for this join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have an SQL query, the index can only really help you if the first column in the index is part of the query.

Your query joins `su.uid = u.uid` and the optimizer will not be able to use that to reference the first column in the subscription primary key index.

You should either reverse the order of the columns in the primary key, or alternatively, you should add a foreign key index, or an independent index on the `uid`